# Retrieving Accelerometer Values?

Tags: iphone, xcode, accelerometer

I want to retrieve the iPhone's accelerometer values and print them into a label.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please leave out the fluff and stick to the question. @Bill the lizard's edit, which you essentially rolled back, was a far superior question.

Comment: Nobody has raged at you. Please see [Other people can edit my stuff?!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in viewDidLoad method of your ViewController which is UIAccelerometerDelegate:

```
UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accelerometer.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
accelerometer.delegate = self;
```

Then add this method:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration 
{
    // here you can use acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z 
}
```