# IOS - Accessing Accelerometer X Y Z Values in Realtime

Tags: ios, coordinates, accelerometer, dimensions

I am working on an iphone/ipod touch app that needs to access the acceleration. I am kind of a newb when it comes to iOS development, I usually develop Android applications.

My first question, is how do I instantiatate the accelerometer? In Android I know i can do it like this:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

My second question is with the handling of accelerometer events, specifically getting the X Y and Z values from the accelerometer state. In android I did the following:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    final double curX = event.values[0];
    final double curY = event.values[1];
    final double curZ = event.values[2];
    //more code stuff
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Lazy question -- RTFM.  That's probably why someone downvoted you. This stuff is presented perfectly clearly in apple's doc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Accelerometer Values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659534/retrieving-accelerometer-values)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [event handling documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/EventHandlingStartingPoint/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010755-CH1-SW9) which contains lots of information and further reading about the accelerometer.